How to run websockets with apache
i am tryign to run websockets with apache, but i cant connect...
server.py
from rich.console import Console
import asyncio
import websockets

console = Console()
clients = set()


async def start(websocket):
    clients.add(websocket)
    console.log('[SYS] New client has been connected')
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    finally:
        clients.remove(websocket)
        console.log('[SYS] Client has been removed')


async def main():
    try:
        console.log('[SYS] Initializing...')
        async with websockets.serve(start, "", 8080):
            await asyncio.Future()  # run forever
    except Exception as e:
        console.log(e)


asyncio.run(main())

vhosts mydomain.com.conf (/etc/apache2/sites-available): https://pastebin.com/haGL7z22
When I try to connect to the client at: ws://mydomain.xyz/ws/, I can't and the client returns this error:
The connection was terminated uncleanly with status code 1006 (ABNORMAL).

hmm? my code are almost the same... but i already tried "localhost", 8765

i removed the infinite loop... but still cant connect, also i checked if is there somethign running on port 8080 with lsof -i :8080, and its running

Disregard what I've said. I ran your code. I could connect using a client that I made.

I fixed my problem using this vhost:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.xyz

    LogLevel info proxy:trace5

    ProxyPass "/ws" "ws://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/ws" "ws://localhost:8080/"

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

